# How to make a merge commit with -X theirs without conflicts?

Tags: git, merge

I have a branch `some-branch` and a feature branch `some-branch-with-feature`.

I would like to add a commit to `some-branch` which has the exact contents of the files in `some-branch-with-feature` and which has a parent of the current `some-branch` and the current `some-branch-with-feature`.

AND I DON"T WANT ANY MERGE CONFLICTS.

How do I do that?

Here is what I tried:

```bash
git checkout some-branch
git merge -X theirs some-branch-with-feature -m "merge some-branch-with-feature"
```

The result was:

> CONFLICT (rename/rename): Rename "FILE"->"OTHER_FILE" in branch "HEAD" rename "FILE"-"OTHER FILE" in "some-branch-with-feature"
>
> ... several copies of that above line
>
> CONFLICT (file location): FILE added in HEAD inside a directory that was renamed in some-branch-with-feature, suggesting it should perhaps be moved to OTHER_FILE.
>
> ... several copies of that above line
>
> Auto-merging FILE
>
> ... several copies of that above line
>
> Removing FILE
>
> ... several copies of that above line
>
> Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

How do I `sudo` and `--force` the `-X theirs` to ACTUALLY prefers "theirs"?

Comment: -X theirs handles internal text conflicts, not file level conflicts such as one side renaming a file one way and the other side renaming that file a different way.